# What am I doing wrong in this SQL self join

Tags: sql, postgresql, self-join

I have a table with blog posts assigned to topics with records like so:

| id | blogid | postid | topic | subtopic |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 81829 | 1 | 604136 | foo | 1 |
| 81830 | 60 | 604139 | foo | 1 |
| 81831 | 1 | 604144 | foo | 1 |
| 81832 | 1 | 604144 | bar | 2 |
| 81833 | 88 | 604146 | foo | 1 |
| 81834 | 88 | 604146 | bar | 2 |
| 81835 | 88 | 604146 | bar | 7 |
| 81836 | 51 | 604152 | foo | 1 |
| 81837 | 71 | 604156 | foo | 1 |
| 81838 | 75 | 604160 | foo | 18 |
| 81839 | 75 | 604160 | foo | 8 |
| 81840 | 75 | 604160 | foo | 1 |
| 81841 | 75 | 604160 | foo | 12 |
| 81842 | 75 | 604160 | foo | 16 |
| 81843 | 75 | 604160 | bar | 2 |
| 81844 | 75 | 604160 | bar | 7 |
| 81845 | 118 | 604162 | foo | 18 |
| 81846 | 118 | 604162 | foo | 8 |
| 81847 | 118 | 604162 | foo | 1 |
| 81848 | 118 | 604162 | foo | 13 |

I want to get only postids that have a mix of the two topics. So I want a query that returns the records for postids 604144, 604146, and 604160 only. I think what I need for this purpose is a self join and I've tried this one:

```
select * from topics A, topics B where A.postid = B.postid and A.topic like 'foo' and B.topic like 'bar'
```

But that just gives me duplicates of postids on one topic. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do not use the implizit join using where statement. Use the `join` keyword

Comment: `like` without `%`  as placeholder makes no sence and can be replaced by `=`

Comment: You could potentially join 2 queries from the same table but why not writing a better query?
`SELECT * FROM TOPICS WHERE postid in (604144, 604146, 604160) and (topic like 'foo' or topic like 'bar');`

Comment: What is the logic behind your expected result?

Comment: @SimplyCode suggested select doesn't work because its a big table, and the postids are what I'm trying to find.

Comment: @jens tried select A.* from topics A inner join topics B on A.postid = B.postid where A.topic = 'foo' and B.topic = 'bar' but still not getting it.

Comment: @Steve Honestly I'm still not sure how you want the answer to look like.
Do you want all `unique postids` for topics `foo` and `bar`?  
Or do you want records that share `postid` (so - `not unique`) which has `foo` and `bar` as topics?
What is the relation of the query to `postid`? Why not just find all records with these topics?

Comment: @SimplyCode I see why the example may have been confusing. I added a subtopic column that distintinguishes the records for the same postid. What I want are postids that have both topics. I want to exclude all the postids that have only one topic or the other. The answer below from 9bO3av5fw5 is a workaround, but I'd still like to figure out how to do it with a join.

Comment: @Steve `HAVING` is an aggregation method - like the `WHERE` statement in regular queries.
I think that's the best possible way, merges are complicated and you could achieve this by indirectly grouping on topic but you still have to group by to find non unique topics.
That's why aggregations exist :)

Btw best way to explain what you need is a "Result table" so we know what kind of answer you look for.

Answer (score 4):

There's a little ambiguity in the topic criteria but something more like this perhaps?

```
SELECT postid
FROM topics
GROUP BY postid
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT topic) > 1;
```

Comment: https://extendsclass.com/postgresql/ed676dd to test / modify